# Compare Two List

Tags: c#, linq

I manage a call center.  I am trying to add unanswered calls to a pool.

I have two lists and I am getting these lists from just one table because some of my properties are null and some of them are not null.

Null values mean agents didn't pick up, not null values mean agents catch the call, or call the missed client back later.

The easy part is getting null values from table and adding them to pool.  The hard part is finding out if the agents have called back before adding the missed calls to the pool.

Please see my sample below.  In the example I want to remove items where AgentAnswerTime is not null in `def` list from the "abc" list.

```
List<UnansweredCallList> abc =
    { PhoneNumber = "123123", AgentAnswerTime = "null", CallTime = "12:30:59" },
    { PhoneNumber = "321321", AgentAnswerTime = "null", CallTime = "12:54:50" }

List<AnsweredCallsList> def = 
    { PhoneNumber = "123123", AgentAnswerTime = "10272015 12:31:00", CallTime = "12:30:59" },
    { PhoneNumber = "321321", AgentAnswerTime = "null", CallTime = "12:54:50" }
```

I want this result.

```
List<UnansweredCallList> abc = 
    { PhoneNumber = "321321", AgentAnswerTime = "null", CallTime = "12:54:50" }
```

I tried linq `Except`.

Actual code:

```
var query = (
    from c in db.calls 
    where c.PhoneNO.Length >= 9 && c.AGENT_Answer_Time == null && c.ClientNO != null && c.Call_Time > start_date && c.Call_Time < end_date 
    select new
       {
           c.PhoneNO,
           c.Call_Time,
           c.AGENT_Answer_Time,
           c.ClientNO,
           c.ROBOP
        }).ToList();

 var query = (
    from c in db.calls 
    where c.PhoneNO.Length >= 9 && c.AGENT_Answer_Time != null && c.ClientNO != null && c.Call_Time > start_date && c.Call_Time < end_date 
    select new
        {
            c.PhoneNO,
            c.Call_Time,
            c.AGENT_Answer_Time,
            c.ClientNO,
            c.ROBOP
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: show the code u tried. Linq except is the way to go, you will need a custom comparator

Comment: When both lists come from one table it means the result can be made with just one query from that table.

Comment: could you give example please Martin Staufcik

Comment: can a call be answered and still have AgentAnswerTime null? If some date could be supplied to such call, it looks selecting calls with AgentAnswerTime not null is the result, or is it wrong?

Comment: I have answered your question, but cannot understand why do you fetch the records as two seperate lists since the only difference is the null filter on AGENT_Answer_Time column. Just fetch the records with AGENT_Answer_Time IS NULL, those are the unanswered calls, aren't they?

Comment: Martin Staufcik answer is simple table is not updating , its always adding numbers. and if you call two times and your first if we didn't get your call time value will be null and agent see your number and call you back and new value add to table and time will be not null. there is an "In" and "Out" calls. I am trying to compare them two also.

Answer (score 2):

```
from a in abc 
join d in def on a.PhoneNumber equals d.PhoneNumber
where d.AgentAnswerTime == "null"
select a
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your classes so that AnsweredCallsList extend UnansweredCallList

```
public class UnansweredCallList
{
    public string PhoneNumber;
    public string AgentAnswerTime;
    public string CallTime;
}

public class AnsweredCallsList : UnansweredCallList
{
}
```

Implement the following equality comparer

```
  public class CallListComparer : IEqualityComparer<UnansweredCallList>
    {
        public bool Equals(UnansweredCallList x, UnansweredCallList y)
        {
            return x.PhoneNumber == y.PhoneNumber && y.AgentAnswerTime != "null" || x.AgentAnswerTime != "null";
        }

        public int GetHashCode(UnansweredCallList obj)
        {
            return obj.PhoneNumber.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then, use LINQ.Except:

```
    List<UnansweredCallList> abc = new List<UnansweredCallList>(new UnansweredCallList[]
    {
        new UnansweredCallList() {PhoneNumber="123123" , AgentAnswerTime="null", CallTime="12:30:59"},
        new UnansweredCallList() {PhoneNumber="321321" , AgentAnswerTime="null" , CallTime="12:54:50"}
    });

    List<AnsweredCallsList> def = new List<AnsweredCallsList>(new AnsweredCallsList[]
    {
        new AnsweredCallsList() {PhoneNumber="123123" , AgentAnswerTime="10272015 12:31:00", CallTime="12:30:59"},
        new AnsweredCallsList() {PhoneNumber="321321" , AgentAnswerTime="null" , CallTime="12:54:50"}
    });

    IEnumerable<UnansweredCallList> result = abc.Except<UnansweredCallList>(def, new CallListComparer());

    Console.WriteLine(result.Count<UnansweredCallList>());
```

Comment: Did you try AD.Net's query

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
void Main()
{
    List<Call> unanswered = new List<Call>()
    {
        new Call() { PhoneNumber = "123123", AgentAnswerTime = "null", CallTime = "12:30:59" },
        new Call() { PhoneNumber = "321321", AgentAnswerTime = "null", CallTime = "12:54:50" }
    };

    List<Call> answered = new List<Call>()
    {
        new Call() { PhoneNumber = "123123", AgentAnswerTime = "10272015 12:31:00", CallTime = "12:30:59" },
        new Call() { PhoneNumber = "321321", AgentAnswerTime = "null", CallTime = "12:54:50" }
    };

    var result = unanswered.Where(call =>
    {
        var answeredCall = answered.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PhoneNumber == call.PhoneNumber);

        return answeredCall != null && answeredCall.AgentAnswerTime == "null";
    });

    foreach(var r in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r.PhoneNumber);
    }
}

public class Call
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string AgentAnswerTime { get; set; }
    public string CallTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: always returning null.

Comment: if check my example data ,you can see there is a null and not null value on def. on abc there is a number equals on def "123123" and def time is not null. i just want to compare like this. and return just "321321". but your code always returning null.

Comment: Sorry, it's because `AgentAnswerTime` is set to the string "null" as opposed to null value. I've updated answer.

Comment: AgentAnswerTime is date time field. and i am using code first ef. so i don't need a new class i guess.

Comment: I just included the call class to provide a complete example that would compile & run so you could see how I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx) and pass it a custom IEqualityComparer which you can implement to compare your instances.  That would remove the second instance from your first list because a semantically equal object exists in the second.